# Scraping for a rank number using Nokogiri in Ruby

Tags: web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm still doing some web scraping practice using this article:
https://www.pastemagazine.com/articles/2018/01/the-75-best-tv-shows-on-netflix-2018.html

I'd like to get just the rank number of each show and found what I think is the HTML element:

```
<div class="copy entry manual-ads">
  <p>
    <b class="big">
      "75."
      <i> 
        <a href="https://www.netflix.com/search?q=chewing%20gum&jbv=80130911&jbp=0&jbr=0" class="ovr" target="_blank">Chewing Gum</a>
      </i>
    </b>
  </p>
</div>
```

I'm using the following code to grab just the rank number (in this case, "75."):

```
doc.css("b.big").text
```

However, it returns the rank number along with the show title. How can I get just the rank number?

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
doc.css("b.big").text[/\d+/]
```